# How can I add MATLAB to my PATH?

Tags: macos, matlab, path

I've found Matlab's root folder by using `matlabroot` in matlab.

I know I can add directories to my path using `export PATH = $PATH: ...`

I want to be able to run matlab via my terminal (I'm using a mac).  When I do `export PATH = $PATH: <matlabroot>` I get an error saying that this is not a valid identifier.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces in the path, which shouldn't be there:

```
export PATH = $PATH: <matlabroot>
```

while the right thing would be

```
export PATH=$PATH:<matlabroot>
```